# EventQueue.invokeLater() has some bugs

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

When this code is run everything works fine, but problem comes in main when I change the code inside to be used with `EventQueue.invokeLater()`

```java
package dav.gui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;

public class SplashWindow extends JFrame {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JProgressBar progressBar;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //from here...
        final SplashWindow frame = new SplashWindow();                  frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            frame.setProgress(i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
//to here...
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public SplashWindow() {
        setUndecorated(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        progressBar = new JProgressBar();
        progressBar.setMaximum(100);
        progressBar.setValue(0);
        progressBar.setForeground(Color.CYAN);

        panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        GroupLayout gl_panel = new GroupLayout(panel);
        gl_panel.setHorizontalGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_panel.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap()

                        .addComponent(progressBar, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 420, Short.MAX_VALUE).addContainerGap()));
        gl_panel.setVerticalGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_panel
                        .createSequentialGroup().addGap(245).addComponent(progressBar, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap(31, Short.MAX_VALUE)));
        panel.setLayout(gl_panel);

    }

    public void setProgress(int i) {
        progressBar.setValue(i);
        if (i+1>=progressBar.getMaximum()){
            dispose();}
    }
}
```

changing the main method to

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
final SplashWindow frame = new SplashWindow();                  frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                        frame.setProgress(i);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

No exception but it doesn't work as expected and as you all know using `EventQueue` is preferable than working inside a main method due to EDT.

But the following works.

```java
final SplashWindow frame = new SplashWindow();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            frame.setProgress(i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Though progress bar gets null at some point and oops! `NullPointerException` is thrown. As you can see am making a custom `SplashWindow` instead of the built in one. Need help and please don't point out some libraries.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) `.. SplashWindow ..` See also [`SplashScreen`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/SplashScreen.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with `EventQueue.invokeLater`, it's all in how you are using it.

This...

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //...
    }
});
```

is saying, at some point in the future, do this.  BUT, you immediately follow it up with...

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    frame.setProgress(i);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

which is probably going to execute BEFORE `invokeLater` has had a chance to run.

A overall better solution would be to use `SwingWorker` instead and start it within the `EventQueue.invokeLater`, once you have ensured that the state of the UI has been established.

Remember, Swing is not only single threaded, it is NOT thread safe.  This means that not only should you not block the main UI thread (ie the Event Dispatching Thread), should also not update the UI, or anything it relies on, from outside of it

See [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details